# MST or not without children ?

Tags: graph-theory

I've got an undirected weighted graph G with c:E(G)->IR.
Now I want to find a spanning tree, such that a node v arbitrary, shall be an internal node, and among all spanning trees, in which v is only an internal node, it has got minimal weight.

My Idea:

Use Kurskal. If v is an internal node than stop.
But if v is not an internal node I'm not sure what to do.

Do you know how this could be solvable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have children either. People have been telling me I should get a dog.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary that $v$ have degree more than $1$. Kruskal is a good start. I would then leverage the cycle property and cut property here. Add in $v$'s lowest-weight unused edge and remove the heaviest edge already in the tree on the cycle created.